# What US state does Katniss Everdeen live in?

Tags: the-hunger-games

*The Hunger Games* says that the remains of the U.S. are 12 districts. But where are they placed? What states?

Comment: Grr, was about to post an answer from the books, but closed instead. For your note though, Katniss mentions that District 12 was built in [Appalachia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachia). She mentions this in Chapter 3 of the first book.

Answer (score 4):

In *Catching Fire*, a [map of Panem](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/thehungergames/images/4/42/Panem_map.png/revision/latest?cb=20140126041646) is visible during one scene. The official map indicates the general location of [District 12](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/thehungergames/images/2/2c/Hunger_Games_Exhibition_Map.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150423151439) in Panem (which, it should be noted, does not occupy the same size as the modern-day United States, due to apparent flooding).

District 12 is in Eastern United States, most probably Virginia, North Carolina, or South Carolina.

Edit: Given that District 12 is the 'coal district', it's unlikely to be North Carolina as the state [has no coal deposits](http://www.sourcewatch.org/index.php/North_Carolina_and_coal#Coal_resources), however [Virginia has bituminous and semi-bituminous coal deposits in the Appalchian Mountains](http://www.virginiaplaces.org/geology/coal.html).

Comment: I always assumed District 12 was [West Virginia.](http://www.friendsofcoal.org/a-history-of-coal-in-west-virginia.html)